# Flask RESTful API structure

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm attempting to create a simple RESTful style api with flask. I want to send the server some data, have the server run the data through two models I have in parallel before returning an output.

My question is the following. I Would like to pass the data through two models in parallel, so I'm assuming I will need multiprocessing. Additionally, I would not like to load the models each time the api is being called, so I would like to preload the models in advance. Any idea of how to best structure this? My api code snippet sample is below

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
        data = request.data
        #process data in parallel with preloaded models
        return "result"
    else:
        #return error code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Essentially my question boils down to

1. How can send the data through 2 models in parallel (e.g. with multiprocessing or whatever)
2. How can I preload the models in advance so they do not have to be set up each time `api_message()` is called, as that would be a lot of overhead.

I am new to Flask so any advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'd expect that returning a string that just *contains* 415 isn't the same as an actual response with that code; have you tested this?

Comment: I know it's not. This is just a code snippet. My actual questions pertains more to how to run 2 models in parallel in and load them in advance of the method being called.

Comment: If you control the server instance, you can load your models with the instance. Also, if you just want to run your models in parallel, do you need to send data in parallel? Can you just have one wait on the other and only run them when they both receive the data?

Comment: @postoronnim I do control the instance. And basically I don't want to run model 1 and then when thats done run model 2, as it will be slow. It's the same data input to each so I'd rather send it to model 1 and model 2 and then once both are finished sent the output. How do I structure this?

Comment: So, if it's the same data, send it once and then you can run both models in parallel using multiprocessing.

Comment: @postoronnim  Given your answer, could you post a code snippet of the structure based on what I have provided as an answer so that I have an idea of how to proceed, and so that I can accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it looks like all you need to do load your models is to instantiate them in your flask application. Then, if the module you intend to use to work on your (preloaded) models were called "process_data" and the models were called "Model1" and "Model2", then your code, which I modified slightly and added multiprocessing, would look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import multiprocessing
import process_data
from models import Model1, Model2

model1 = Model1()
model2 = Model2()

app = Flask(__name__)

models = [model1, model2]

@app.route('/api', methods = ['POST'])
def process_in_parallel():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
        data = request.data
    else:
        #return error code

    def worker(model, data):
        process_data(model, data)
        return

    jobs = []
    for model in models:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker(model, data))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Do I need a a separate function under `@app.route` ?